# TextView how to MARQUEE only one circle on Android

Tags: android, textview

While click TextView I want to do 2 things.
I want to set TextView ellipsize to END if it is MARQUEE.
Otherwise, I want to set TextView ellipsize to MARQUEE.
Below is my code:

```
tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(tv.getEllipsize().equals(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE)) {
        tv.setSelected(true);
            tv.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
    }
    else {
        tv.setSelected(true);
        tv.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
    }
    }
});
```

But I want to the MARQUEE only one circle.
When it finish one circle, it auto set to `TextUtils.TruncateAt.END`.
How can I arrive it?